# trigger event after several ajax calls succeeded

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, triggers, reactive-extensions-js

I wonder which is the best approach to trigger an event after several (unordered) ajax calls finished.

To make it a bit clearer, I would like to call a Method doSomethingGreat() which triggers several ajax calls, the order in which those succeed ins unnecessary. I just want to trigger an event 'SomethingGreatFinished' when all of those calls succeeded. I also don't want to chain these calls, because that would be lacking performance and would be totally against the idea of asynchronous programming.

I wonder if a.) there is a common pattern for that, b.) this can be done with the Reactive Extensions for JavaScript (RxJs) or c.) with native jquery features.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: IIRC, you can only have a maximum of two simultaneous HTTP requests to the same server. Of course, two in parallel is better than one-by-one done in serial, so you're right to be asking this question, but just be aware you won't get 7 simultaneous ajax calls.

Comment: Good point about the maximum number of simultaneous requests but, if I remember correctly, this is a browser setting, and some browsers use different values. http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2008/07/21/internet-explorer-8-and-maximum-concurrent-connections.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RxJS will allow you to do this using the ForkJoin operator, this operator takes N observables with a value and creates one observable that fires with an array when all N observables complete.

See Matthew Podwysocki's blog post about this operator: http://codebetter.com/blogs/matthew.podwysocki/archive/2010/04/23/introduction-to-the-reactive-extensions-for-javascript-going-parallel-with-forkjoin.aspx

Comment: I think that's exactly what I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [.ajaxStop()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/).

However, that `callback` will fire on every single ajax request that completes. So in order to know when your **last** request completes, you need either to invoke [.ajaxStart()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) aswell, or you need to iterate a `global variable` for each request you fire and `decrement` it on `.ajaxStop()`. If that variable reaches `zero`, all your request have completed.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many calls are being made, then set a variable to that number, and decrement it each time an AJAX completion event occurs. When the variable reaches zero, 'SomethingGreat' has happened.

Comment: That's what I do by now, but I thought there must be a nicer way to accomplish it. Maybe with the Reactive Extensions for JS?