# multiple asynchronous $.ajax calls followed by function after all have executed

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, callback

I'm doing 3 asynchronous ajax requests.

Afterwards I need a function executed but only if all 3 requests have finished.

How would I accomplish that?

Due to our framework, I'm limited to the latest 1.4 release.

Thanks,
Wesley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it with Reactive Extension for jQuery. Have a look at this question: [trigger event after several ajax calls succeeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296974/trigger-event-after-several-ajax-calls-succeeded)

Answer (score 2):

You need to have all the response handlers call the same scope/function, and keep track of the returned requests there.  Only move on if all requests return.  Don't forget to handle error cases.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and a very limited way would be just to nest your ajax calls. But that only works if you make those calls at the same time in the same place.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  success: function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "test2.html",
      success: function(){
        // n level nesting
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: That's synchronous and will slow down the loading of these ajax requests as they're done 1 by 1.

Comment: @Wesley no, that's not "synchronous", it's "serialised".   Each call here is technically _asynchronous_, but the next one isn't triggered until the previous one has completed.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Andrius's answer, I do something similar to his all the time:

```
function f1(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    success: function(data){
      //do something
      f2();
    }
  });
}

function f2(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "test2.html",
    success: function(data){
      //do something else
      //maybe call f1() if you want to loop again?
    }
  });
}
```

I chain together many calls this way.  Sometimes I put `setTimeout(function(){f2()},1000);` If I want to have a slight pause between calls.

And my application requires constant polling from the server, so I have my last one in the chain call the first one.  So it will loop forever with only one current call outstanding (so I don't hammer the server with requests)